# 100% height of window on resize - Javascript

Tags: jquery, resize

I have the following to get 100% height and width of a div (.home-bg) to the window.

The resize isn't working:

```
// HOME-BG HEIGHT 100%

// global vars
var winWidth = $(window).width();
var winHeight = $(window).height();

// set initial div height / width
$('.home-bg').css({
    'width': winWidth,
    'height': winHeight,
});
});

// make sure div stays full width/height on resize
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.home-bg').css({
        'width': winWidth,
        'height': winHeight,
    });
});
```

When I take away the last `});` it works but I of course get an error.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Can you not use `height: 100%; width: 100%;` on the div? That aside, you have an extra `})` set there which will cause issues, and both CSS objects have trailing commas on the last property.

Comment: there are too many closing brackets in your .css-function, where you set initial div height / width.
@RoryMcCrossan, i think trailing commas on the last property only throw errors on internet explorer. but they should never be used

Comment: You need to recalculate sizes on resize.  `$('.home-bg').css({
        'width': $(window).width()...`. But anyway, why not CSS?

Comment: I originally tried the CSS solution but came across a strange bug in Safari on iOS7 (fixed in iOS8) where it created a long viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recalculate sizes on resize.

```js
var $window = $(window);

function fullSize() {
   $('.home-bg').css({
     width: $window.width(),
     height: $window.height()
   }).html($window.width() + 'x' + $window.height());  
}

fullSize();
$window.resize(fullSize);
```

```css
.home-bg {
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-bg"></div>
```